# Magento 2.4.3 - Refused to execute Script

Tags: javascript, theme, magento2.4.3, static-content

I just created a staging environment for my live server and I have some issues with my porto theme after that.

I can see it in the inspector "Refused to execute script "script path/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/nb_NO/js/jquery.stellar.min.js" And when I go to my stage environment I do not find jquery.stellar.min.js but I do find it on my live environment. I did read that this could be an issue, any suggestions on how to fix this?

I have tried to remove deployed_version.txt file and run [image]

No luck

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run remove `pub/static/frontend`, and `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend`, before deploy static content:

```
rm -r pub/static/frontend
rm -r var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area frontend
```

If the issue persists, assume your Magento root folder is `/var/www/html`, and run the command: `grep -r jquery.stellar.min /var/www/html` to see if jquery.stellar.min.js is declared anywhere the add results to your question (run that command in both staging and live server). Also, add the screenshot for the error in the console tab in the Developer tool too. I'll help.

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that.